# Webpack splitting code into separate modules included via npm, how to compile es6?

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to write a system of modular components that can be dynamically loaded at runtime with webpack. For example, when the user switches tabs, the code to display the content of the new tab should only load when the user clicks on that tab.

Here is some of the code that accomplishes this (quite nicely, I might add):

```
onrender(){    
        this.observe("route", (route) => {
            if(route.length>0){
                this.set("loading", true);

                this.get("pages."+route).loadComponent((component) => {
                    this.components.Page = component.Component;
                    this.set("loading", false);
                });
            }
        });

    },

    data: {
        pages: {
            "#hello": {
                name: "Hello",
                loadComponent: (callback) => {
                    require.ensure([], () => {
                        callback(require("./page_component/hello/hello.js"));
                    });
                }
            },
            "#world": {
                name: "World",
                loadComponent: (callback) => {
                    require.ensure([], () => {
                        callback(require("./page_component/world/world.js"));
                    });
                }
            },
            "#activity": {
                name: "Individual Activity",
                loadComponent: (callback) => {
                    require.ensure([], () => {
                        callback(require("./page_component/individual_activity/assets/js/src/main.js"));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

I have gotten this working fabulously, with one caveat. I'm using ES6, and the babel-loader to load it. The modules containing the functionality, templates, styles etc. for the tabs all have to be directly contained within the directory structure of the app, like so (see: page_components directory):

```
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── page_components
│   │       ├── hello
│   │       ├── individual_activity
│   │       └── world
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

I would prefer each page component to be its own package, with a package.json, and included via for example: `require("individial_activity")`, for purposes of code organization.

The problem is, it appears that webpack doesn't run external modules (such as the modules included via `node_modules`) through any loader, and as such I get errors about unexpected symbols when trying to load ES6 code.

I tried such things as `require("babel-loader!individual_activity")` and, `require("babel-loader!individual_activity/path/to/main.js")` to no avail.

Is what I'm trying to do not the normal way of doing things? Should I keep all my code for all the modules in the same directory structure? Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./assets/js/main.js'],
    output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                dead_code: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unsafe: false,
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: false
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en.js/)
    ]
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice idea to keep your concerns separate, but I think you'd be going overkill by making each section of your app an npm package. Allow npm to handle external dependancies and one off libraries, not highly dependent parts of your application.

If all you are looking for is cleaner `require()` statements, try adding your js directories to your `modulesDirectories` config:

```
resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules',
                         'bower_components',
                         'assets/js',
                         'assets/js/page_components'],
},
```

Should then allow you to require modules directly inside `page_components` without the need for a path or extension, e.g. `require('individual_activity')`